# SQL Server: how to set if condition in where

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause, sqlanywhere

I need some help with a SQL Server query. I have three tables documents, modules and folders.

`Document` table

```
Id Title type data folderid
```

`Module` table

```
Id label moduleId folderid
```

`Folder` table

```
Id label
```

If type = 1 in document table, I want to get `folderid` from `module` table otherwise it should take id from itself

I tried below query

```
SELECT  m.*
  FROM modules m
  LEFT JOIN documents ed ON CAST(m.moduleId AS VARCHAR) = ed.data
  where m.folderId = 35 OR ed.folderid =35
```

But I am not able to write if condition in where can anyone tell me how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this     SELECT  m.*
    FROM modules m
    LEFT JOIN documents ed ON ( CAST(m.moduleId AS VARCHAR) = ed.data )
    where (ed.type = 1  and m.folderId = 35) 
       or (ed.type <> 1 and ed.folderid =35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be a case expression.

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM modules m
LEFT JOIN documents ed ON CAST(m.moduleId AS VARCHAR) = ed.data
where case when type = 1 
    then m.folderId 
    else ed.folderid 
    end = 35
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT  m.*
  FROM modules m
  LEFT JOIN documents ed ON CAST(m.moduleId AS VARCHAR) = ed.data
  where (type = 1 and m.folderId = 35)
     OR (type <> 1 and ed.folderid = 35)
```